# C# and SQLite: Resource to Array

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm querying a database with SQLite. I'm trying to get data from this database, save it in an array, then return to the controller. I need to present this data using a `foreach` loop in my view.

```
string sql = "select * from Tasks Where UserId = " + userId.ToString();
using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(connString))    
{
    SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, conn);
    conn.Open();
    using (SQLiteDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (rdr.Read()) 
        {
            //here is what i would do in PHP
            $array[$i]['name'] = $rdr[i]["name"];
            $array[$i]['key']  $rdr[$i]["key"];
        }
    }
}

return array;
```

Comment: You should check what SQL Injection is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, learn to use parameterised queries not string concatenation as this will help prevent SQL injection attacks.

```
string sql = "select * from Tasks Where UserId = @userId";
```

Also, if you create a class to represent a record in your `Tasks` table then you can build instances of this object and return them in a list which will make using the code easier since instead of having untyped arrays, you will have an object with properties (in your view you can do `foreach (var task in Model)` where `Model` is a `List<Task>`.

```
public class Task
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
}

var tasks = new List<Task>(); // create a list to populate with tasks

using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(connString))    
{
    var command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, conn);
    command.Parameters.Add("@userId", userId); // only do .ToString on userId if the column is a string.

    connection.Open();
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
    {
        while (reader.Read()) 
        {
            var task = new Task();
            task.Id = (int)reader["id"]; // the name of the column in the reader will match the column in the Tasks table.
            task.Name = (string)reader["name"];
            task.Key = (string)reader["key"];

            tasks.Add(task);
        }
    }
}

return tasks;
```

Instead of writing all the query logic and creating objects, you can use frameworks called `Object Relational Mappers (ORM)` to do this for you. There are a number of them around, some more simple than others. A MicroORM may suit your purposes, they are simple and easy to use (I have built one called [MicroLite](http://microliteorm.wordpress.com) but there are others such as dapper or PetaPoco. If you want something more powerful, NHibernate and Entity Framework are popular choices.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I have an error with task.Name = reader["name"]; Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?). toString() gives IndexOutOfRangeException

Comment: Do you mean `reader["name"].ToString()` throws an `IndexOutOfRangeException`? I'm guessing at the names since you are using `SELECT *` the reader will throw that exception if the name does not exist in the result set. There are methods on the reader to get the value as an integer or date etc which may be more suitable than accessing the object value via the indexer and casting.